# compose<any> how sould I type this stuff?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I got question for you! I migrate my entier App on typeScript but got some difficulties with compose function  ... (no worries for this other any I already fix then except the compose())

With `compose(...)` (without 'any') I get the following :

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): Route', gave the following error.
>       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass | FunctionComponent | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
>         Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'.
>     Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps, context?: any): Route', gave the following error.
>       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass | FunctionComponent | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
>         Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'.  TS2769

That's why I would like to replace it and type it.

this is my code:

/container.ts

```
//@ts-ignore
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose, AnyAction, Dispatch } from "redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { getProfile, updateProfile } from "../../../services/clients/user";
import { updateUserInitial } from "../../../actions/initialUser";
import { IStoreState } from "../../typeScriptInclude";
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import { Profile } from "./component/utilities/includeTypeScript";
import { IEditAccountProps as Props } from './component/EditAccount';

interface IupDateWalterInitailUserPropsType {
  walterUser: {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
  };
}

interface IMapStateToProps{
  isConnect: boolean;
  walterUser: any;
  upDateProfile: any;
}

interface IMapDispatchToProps{
  upDateWalterInitailUser: any;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IStoreState): IMapStateToProps => {
  return {
    isConnect: state.isConnect,
    walterUser: getProfile(),
    upDateProfile: (data: Profile) => updateProfile(data)
  };
};

type ApplicationDispatch = ThunkDispatch<IStoreState, void, AnyAction> &
  Dispatch;

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ApplicationDispatch,
): IMapDispatchToProps => ({
  upDateWalterInitailUser: (form: IupDateWalterInitailUserPropsType) =>
    dispatch(updateUserInitial(form))
});

export default compose<any>(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
);
```

/index.ts

```
import EditAccount from "./component/EditAccount";
import container from './container';

export default container(EditAccount);
```

The things is I tried a lot of thing to type it, but nothing to do...
I tried

```
// Which props define our new component : IProps - IInjectedProps
type ContainerProps = Omit<Props, keyof InjectedProps>;

export default compose<Props, ContainerProps>(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
);
```

I take off `withRouter` but I get the following :

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.  TS2554

Obviously but Why it's not working with my first solution... need to understand

Thx everyone best regards.

Comment: I think you should apply the composed function on a component. What component are you trying to `connect` here?

Comment: I add more details on the post ;) but to > EditAccount

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error when you just do `compose(...)`? If so, what's the error? If not, why do you want to type it?

Comment: My bad I don't understand what you mean at first but I get : ```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2,...
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any> | FunctionComponent<any> | ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>>'.  TS2769```

Answer (score 0):

That's a `connect` problem, not `compose`. As I recall, there is a mismatch in the `react` versions in `node_modules/@types`. `react-redux` types folder has it's own `node_modules` in it and reads `react` types from it. It's a different version than the actual `react` folder in the root `node_modules`. So, what happens is, `ComponentClass` type is read from two different `.d.ts` files and get mismatched, hence the error.

You can `@ts-ignore` the `connect` lines and forget about it. That wasn't very appealing to me, so what I did (although it's a hack and a little tidious) was I deleted the `node_modules` from both `root/node_modules/@types/react-native` and `root/node_modules/@types/react-redux`. Doing so, enabled `tslint` to read the types from the same file from `root/node_modules/@types/react`. It fixes the problem, but each time you install or uninstall a package, those `node_modules` show up again. You'll have to delete those each time (I have a cmd batch file for that). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean except it's a modules problems :/ but as I understand I need to delete my modules and reinstall ?

Comment: No, you only need to delete `root/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules` and `root/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules`. You can navigate to those folders and see for yourself. There's `react` types module in there which is an older version.

Comment: okok I did it work but if I must do that every time as you said earlier it's tidious and it's a hack ... so there is no legit thing to fix it ? cause if i deploy it, it could crash at anytime ...

Comment: Well, I haven't found it so far. We have to wait until those libraries get synced up and add the proper `react` types version. You can create a batch file and do all that with one command after installs. I can give you the batch file as an edit to the answer if you'd like.

Comment: My bad an other error just appear ... ```JSX element type 'Navigation' does not have any construct or call signatures.  TS2604```` if would like to test your bash with pleasure !

Comment: Ok, I guess you need those type definitions for other components as well, whereas I didn't. I guess your best bet is to `@ts-ignore` `connect`'s for now. Those node_modules will be back if you install any package, as I said. I would also suggest to get rid of `connect` alltogether and use hooks instead (`useDispatch`, `useSelector`).

Comment: ok to ```useDispatch, useSelector``` instead of ```connect()``` should fix my problem ?

Comment: I believe it should. As I said, your error is coming from `connect`'s typing, which you will no longer need. `redux` hooks have no such problems as far as I'm aware. Also, you'll need less code and maintenance if you use hooks instead.

Comment: I ll try it and I come back to tell you if it's work ;) thx for helping